# HTML5 Input - Date (including Day) for iOS

Tags: ios, html, forms, input, mobile-safari

I am trying to use an HTML5 input in MobileSafari to get date. When I use '**date**', it shows three reels, **Month**, **Day (#)**, **Year**:

**Jan | 4th | 1948**

When I select '**datetime**', it shows 4 reels for date and time:

**Wed Mar 6 | 3 | 05 | PM**

Is there a way to make it just show the **'Wed Mar 6'** from the '**datetime**' and the year in the native selector? I'd like users to be able to see the day when they make the date selection instead of having to count how many days until Friday. I don't need the time selection, But I want the date formatting from that input type.

Answer (score 0):

It's browser-implementation dependant sorry.  You'd have to make your own browser and make them use that.  As far as I'm aware HTML5 isn't actually 100% out yet; w3c are still tweaking it and browsers can't agree on how to render the new elements.

If it's absolutely essential you may have to consider using a flash or java plugin object.

Comment: *consider using a flash or java plugin object* for iOS' mobile Safari?

Comment: yeah didn't think about that bit :P